# Adding Notification Event to OPC UA Client C# application

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have not thus far enjoyed the seeming lack of development documentation for OPC UA Client, but I seem to have code close to doing what I want it to do. I am developing an integration to handle the notification events thrown from the OPC UA Server, to be handled in our security system.

Currently I am adding the Notification Event to every single node found, just to see if I can get ANY notification event to fire.  Thus far though, I have been unsuccessful in getting even a single notification to fire.  Any help or direction on getting this work correctly, would be highly appreciated.  If I need to be more detailed in what I'm doing or trying to perform, please ask.

```
    private IntegratorContext   GetUAConnection()
    {
        var config = new ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
            ApplicationName = "OpcUAClient",
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
            SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
            {
                ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = Utils.Format(@"CN={0}, DC={1}", "OpcUAClient", IntegratorGlobals.ServerUrl) },
                TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
                TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true,
                AddAppCertToTrustedStore = true
            },
            TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
            TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
            ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 }
        };

        config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client);
        if (config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
        {
            config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) => { e.Accept = (e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted); };
        }

        _Context.UaSession = Session.Create(config,
            new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, new EndpointDescription(IntegratorGlobals.ServerUrl)), true, "69", 60000,
            null, null).Result;

        _Context.UaSession.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward,
            ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true,
            (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out var cp, out var refs);

        var subscription = new Subscription(_Context.UaSession.DefaultSubscription) { PublishingInterval = 1000 };
        _Context.UaSession.AddSubscription(subscription);
        subscription.Create();

        foreach (var rd in refs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rd.DisplayName + ": " + rd.BrowseName + ", " + rd.NodeClass);

            //CreateMonitoredItem(_Context.UaSession, subscription, rd.NodeId, MonitoringMode.Reporting);

            _Context.UaSession.Browse(null, null,
                ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(rd.NodeId, _Context.UaSession.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward,
                ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true,
                (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out var nextCp,
                out var nextRefs);

            //Individual 
            foreach (var nextRd in nextRefs)
            {
                CreateMonitoredItem(_Context.UaSession, subscription, new NodeId(nextRd.NodeId.Identifier.ToString()), nextRed.DisplayName.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("+ " + nextRd.DisplayName + ": " + nextRd.BrowseName + ", " + nextRd.NodeClass);
            }
        }

        _Context.UaSession.DeleteSubscriptionsOnClose = true;

        return _Context.VerifyControlConnection() ? _Context : new IntegratorContext();
    }

    private void CreateMonitoredItem(
        Session session, Subscription subscription, NodeId nodeId, string name)
    {
        var monitoredItem = new MonitoredItem(subscription.DefaultItem)
        {
            StartNodeId = $"ns=69;s={name}",
            AttributeId = Attributes.EventNotifier,
            DisplayName = name,
            MonitoringMode = MonitoringMode.Reporting
            //SamplingInterval = mode == MonitoringMode.Sampling ? 1000 : 0,
            //QueueSize = 0,
            //DiscardOldest = true
        };

        monitoredItem.Notification += IOnNotification;
        subscription.AddItem(monitoredItem);
        subscription.ApplyChanges();
    }

    private void IOnNotification(MonitoredItem monitoreditem, MonitoredItemNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _Context.QueueRequest(IntegratorConstants.FunctionType.Alert, monitoreditem.DisplayName);
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use Attributes.EventNotifier and not Attributes.Value?

Comment: I changed code to reflect that suggestion, but Notifications still don't happen

Comment: Have you verified with another client that any of the Nodes in this server even have an EventNotifier attribute that suggests events are available and that it's generating events at all?

Comment: @JonathanHansen, Have you made any progress in the mean time? I'm currently facing the same issues with not getting notified when variables changed in the OPC UA Server

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the [OPC UA .NET Standard library](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/) there is an callback, to get all events as bulk notification per subscription. I only used the `FastDataCallback` but it should look like:

```cs
//...
m_subscription.FastEventCallback = OnEventsFired;
//...
private void OnEventsFired(
    Subscription subscription, 
    EventNotificationList notification, 
    IList<string> stringTable) {


  for (int ii = 0; ii < notification.Events.Count; ii++)
  {
     Opc.Ua.Client.MonitoredItem monitoredItem = subscription.FindItemByClientHandle(notification.Events[ii].ClientHandle);
    _Context.QueueRequest(IntegratorConstants.FunctionType.Alert, monitoreditem.DisplayName);
  }
}
```